# NSDictionary allKeys returns NSArray, instead of NSSet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

I wonder what is the decision behind NSDictionary method allKeys, to return an NSArray, instead of an NSSet, which would make more sense, since there is no guarantee about the order of the returned array and moreover, a key is unique

Comment: Objection; Speculation!

Comment: This is not primarily opinion based, and there is tons of precedent for similar questions.

Comment: Whilst there is precedent for such a question, you aren't asking the original developers and all answers can only be speculation.For that matter, this is NextStep code you are asking about.  The answer may well be "API compatibility with a much earlier time than you are considering".

Comment: @JeffLaing true, I still think a good answer can be found that can benefit everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as everybody is guessing...

As the OP said, every key is unique. For either the array or set case the dictionary code has to collect the keys - the cost of that applies to both. In the set case each key has to be added to the set, which involves a (pointless as it turns out) test of membership, while in the array case no membership test is required - the cost of adding to an array should be smaller than adding to a set. Array wins.

Comment: Your saying an NSSet insertion would require an O(n) duplicate search?  If apple was so concerned about NSSet performance why would they use it in many cases but not this one.

Comment: A look at the source code shows me they use O(1) hash table for NSSet. Duplicate resolution is no impact.

Comment: @JustinMeiners - I carefully didn't mention O() ;-) But are you saying you've examined the source or array and set and determined the cost of the check is *zero* and that sans-check the cost of adding an item to an array and to a set are equal? But unless there are comments in the code everybody is just having fun here, arguments can be made for either choice - and it may even have been arbitrary.

Comment: first comment I was genuinely asking if you thought that was the case. I think with O(1) for the insert and NSSet's usage elsewhere Im going to guess its not performance, but thats definitely not definitive.

Comment: @JustinMeiners - Yup, as good as guess as any is the programmer typed NS and then placed their finger above A & S, closed their eyes... Must get back to real work!

Comment: And then stayed that way on one of the most important classes on Next, Mac for 9 releases, and iOS for 7...

Comment: @JustinMeiners - Unless the developers were incredibly stupid, adding a pointer to an NSArray is going to be significantly less costly than adding one to an NSSet.  The set needs all the overhead of the array, plus the hash table, which adds a needless size and performance overhead.

Answer (score 1):

And, aside from what Justin said, if you actually wanted a list of dictionary keys you'd have to get the NSSet and then convert that to an NSArray.  If you simply want to test key existence, OTOH, you can go directly against the dictionary and don't need the set.